# Running 400 Hz, 380 V spindle motor on 220 V, 3-phase VFD

Tags: motor, efficiency, performance

I just (mistakenly) purchased a 380 V (400 Hz) spindle motor and I have a 220 V, 3-phase VFD.  The manufacturer said the winding is a special configuration that performs equally well with either voltage. I don't believe that's true. If this is a star with 380 V, there is 380V/√3 = 220 V across each coil. So if 220 V is used it becomes 220V/√3 = 127 V, a 42% reduction.  If it is a delta each coil sees direct voltage so they would see 220 V instead of 380 V. Again a 42% reduction. Although this is voltage differences, will the power be impacted?  Thanks.

Comment: With reduced voltage, the motor won't be able to operate at the rated power or the rated efficiency. The difference between 380V and 220V is enough that unless you specced your motor to be crazy oversize to begin with, it won't work for your application and if that's what you did, it will work but it will run at poor efficiency.

Comment: Do you have access to all 6 wires from the 3 windings, which would possibly allow you to switch the motor between star/wye and delta yourself? If it's currently wired for 380V star/wye and you rewire it to delta, then wouldn't it then be correct for 220v?

Comment: At the total absence of information, it may be better to start with lower voltage per coil and, without loading, see if it heats after some minutes. Motor should not heat above 60°C without load, i think, while wire acceptable temperature is more than 100°C.

Comment: So have you checked what the manufacturer did with the windings?

Comment: 1) I did not over spec motor sizing, so I greatly concerned that a 42% reduction in power is the case and have to agree. 2) Supplier hasn't (wont?) answer question about star vs delta winding, or access to wires. 3) Agree on the heat test. Hard pill to swallow.  Any more insight appreciated. Thanks.